# Script not included with wp_enqueue_scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have learned to include scripts the following way.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'woomps_ajax_frontend' );
function woomps_ajax_frontend() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'woomps_sub_slider', plugins_url( '/js/woomps-ajax-frontend.js', dirname(__FILE__)) , array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    $parameters =  array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        );
    wp_localize_script( 'woomps_sub_slider', 'subpost', $parameters);
}
```

This should fire of my jQuery:

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '.button_sub_chooser', function() {
alert("test");
jQuery.ajax({
    url : subpost.ajax_url,
    type : 'post',
    data : {
        action : 'woomps_update_subscription_chooser',
    },
    success : function( response ) {
        jQuery('#button_sub_chooser').effect( "bounce", "slow" );

    }
});

return false;
})
```

When this is clicked:

```
<a id="button_shake" class="button_sub_chooser" '.$woomps_ajax_url.'>VElg denne</a>
```

But wp_enqueue_scripts does not fire of the jQuery. If i just call the function like this `woomps_ajax_frontend()` it will fire. Why does it work when called like a function and not through wp_enqueue_scripts?

Comment: Is your `woomps-ajax-frontend.js` visible on the page? When you inspect and go to Sources tab, you should see it in the plugins js folder. If not, then it's not enqueued correctly.

Comment: No, it was not. The PHP function was located in a /my-plugin/includes/code.php and included with require_once from /my-plugin/my-plugin.php. I moved all PHP functions too my main plugin file and suddenly the JS was loaded correctly and the AJAX worked. I think i have seen this somewhere in the codex, but cant find back to it. If anyone knows why, please feel to share as its the answer to this question.

Comment: If it works when you move it to your main plugin file, that means that the folder you're trying to fetch doesn't have correct path (that is, it's not fetching it at all).

Comment: Its fetching. Because i have the fiter right after the enqueue, and the button is showing. Its just that the JS dont get included with enqueue.

Comment: Then something with `plugins_url( '/js/woomps-ajax-frontend.js', dirname(__FILE__))` must be the issue.

Comment: Yea, your right that will not work in the subfolder. It will output the subfolder where the PHP sits before /js/. The code works in my-plugin/my-plugin.php with this `plugin_dir_url(__FILE__). 'js/woomps-ajax-frontend.js'`. But lets say i move the code to my-plugin/includes/code.php and do i require_once from my-plugin/my-plugin.php. Now i need to change the plugins_url('/woo-multiple-package-subscriptions/js/woomps-ajax-frontend.js') which i tested outputs correct URL. All other stays the same and it should work. But now it will not find the jQuery even tought it has the correct URL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94593/discussion-between-robin-pedersen-and-dingo-d).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this `plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)` insted of `plugins_url()`.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'woomps_ajax_frontend' );

function woomps_ajax_frontend() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'woomps_sub_slider', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__). 'js/woomps-ajax-frontend.js' , array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

    $parameters =  array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        );
    wp_localize_script( 'woomps_sub_slider', 'subpost', $parameters);


}
```

Comment: Tried it and it did not work. Logged it and they output the same. As said, the .js runs when i run it as a function but not when enqueue.

Comment: @RobinPedersen Can you please check ctrl+u is your file display or not ?

Comment: When wp_enqueue_script in a subolder with this `plugins_url('/woo-multiple-package-subscriptions/js/woomps-ajax-frontend.js')` it is not added anywhere while inspecting. If i do it from the main php file: `wp_enqueue_script( 'woomps_sub_slider', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__). 'js/woomps-ajax-frontend.js' , array('jquery'), '1.0', true );` it is added.

Comment: @RobinPedersen So what's the issue ? you are not able to use this "wp_enqueue_script( 'woomps_sub_slider', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__). 'js/woomps-ajax-frontend.js' , array('jquery'), '1.0', true );" ?

its not working because on plugins_url() didn't get plugin name.

Comment: See my answer below. Could the cause you are talking about be realted to dobbel `wp_enqueue_script`?

Comment: @RobinPedersen No, Did you replace your code with my above answer code ?

Comment: Yes, i did. See comment from nr 3.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code was put in an included (required_once) file which i had enqueue the following way.

```
function woomps_scripts() { 
require_once ('includes/woomps-ajax-sub-chooser.php'); 
} //END woomps_scripts

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','woomps_scripts');
```

If I put the `require_once ('includes/woomps-ajax-sub-chooser.php');` outside this `function woomps_scripts` it got included.

So it seems I cant do wp_enqueue_scripts two times down.