# WordPress script is not adding with wp_enqueue_scripts

Tags: wordpress

My question is similar to [Script not included with wp_enqueue_scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33598774/script-not-included-with-wp-enqueue-scripts).

But the solution there which worked is not working for me. I am posting this question because the above is an old thread and my comment might not get noticed as I saw in the past with other questions. So I am sorry for posting a similar one.

I am building a plugin where I need to include a script file. To do so I have written this inside my plugin:

```
public function stloc_register() {
   add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'enqueue_store_style' ) );
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'stloc_enqueue_cookie_script' ) );
}

...

public function enqueue_store_style() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'store_css', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/css/stloc-admin-style.css', null, '1.0', 'screen' );
}

public function stloc_enqueue_cookie_script() {
   wp_enqueue_script(
      'stloc_cookie_handler',
      plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/stloc.cookie.min.js',
      array( 'jquery', 'jquery-cookie' )
   );
}
```

After the class:

```
if ( class_exists( 'My_Locator' ) ) {
    $my_locator = new My_Locator();
    $my_locator->stloc_register();
}
```

The css `stloc-admin-style.css` is loading fine when I view source of admin pages. But on front end I cannot see the my JavaScript file `stloc.cookie.min.js` reference . I double checked all the paths and they are all rightly written.

Since I need the script file to be available in the front end I am using `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook rather than `admin_init`.

I tried by deactivating and activating back my plugin from plugin page but nothing is working.

Comment: Have you checked that the object of the class is created or not?

Comment: If I have understood correctly, the object is created because I have custom post types and taxonomy registration inside the plugin and when it is activated those are created. Please let me know if I am mistaking.

Comment: Can you please write a constructor with some message printing into it to check whether the object is been created. I believe you have written the enqueue code correctly, so the only thing is that the function is not called properly